# Wrong output for latex2exp commands

Tags: r, latex2exp

I have been using the `latex2exp` package for many years, but ever since it switched to the latest version (using the "raw" syntaxis), it has ceased to function (the old syntaxis does not work either). I am working on Windows and have updated all my R and LaTeX libraries, but I am still encountering issues (I have attached a screenshot).

MWE

```
library(latex2exp)
a <- 1:100
plot(a, a^2, xlab=TeX("$\\alpha$"), ylab=TeX("$\\alpha^2$"))
```

[image: Plot with base plot function]

Also, trying to reproduce this example

```
library(latex2exp)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0, 4, length.out=100)
alpha <- 1:5
data <- map_df(alpha, ~ tibble(v=.*x^., x=x, alpha=.))

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=v, color=as.factor(alpha))) +
    geom_line() + 
    ylab(TeX(r'($\alpha  x^\alpha$, where $\alpha \in 1\ldots 5$)')) +
    ggtitle(TeX(r'(Using $\LaTeX$ for plotting in ggplot2. I $\heartsuit$ ggplot!)')) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-1, 10)) +
    guides(color=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
    scale_color_discrete(labels=lapply(sprintf(r'($\alpha = %d$)', alpha), TeX)) 
    # Note that ggplot2 legend labels must be lists of expressions, not vectors of expressions

print(p)
```

from the library help page [Using latex2exp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html)

I get a plot with all the labels wrong
[image: Plot with ggplot]

Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: I cannot replicate this- are you on packageVersion("latex2exp")
[1] ‘0.9.6’ ?

Comment: Yes, I have just installed R.4.3.1 and updated all the packages

Comment: I just updated to 4.3.1, and this still isn't reproducing for me

Comment: I am on a Mac though, so it could be a Windows issue